# Is there a way to refresh an expired SESSION variable?

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a table. When a user clicks on an item in that table, it takes the id of the table line and sets a session variable, then loads a form.
The session variable is important, as it is the id of the file I need to add to.

When they have filled in the form data it is posted via jquery to a php file, and I then uses the session variable to add the form data to a specific entry in the database.

The problem is this. When the form appears the id is in a session variable, so if they pop off for a cup of tea before filling in the form the session variable may expire.

So when the submit button is pressed it can't add the correct id because it has expired.

I have thought of using a hidden id on the form, but I didn't think this was very secure. Also I thought if I use a hidden field the data may be tampered with before sending.

Is there a way of refreshing the expired session variable, if it doesn't exist?

Comment: No, not really. Why not just extend the timeout period? If getting the cuppa takes more than 15 minutes, then the user deserves the pain of not doing their job.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: how would a cookie be more secure than a hidden form field?

Comment: It's not more secure @MarcB, guess I should've explained that better.

Comment: Expanding on what @MarcB said... Keeping variables around when folks leave their desk is also not secure. You're worried about the security of form variable vs cookie... meanwhile someone else can just sit down at the empty desk and do things regardless.

Comment: As @MarcB says, you can extend the cookie lifetime or, on the other hand, you also can set it to '0' which means that cookie will live "forever" but only in the current browser execution. That is: When the user finally closes the browser the cookie is forcibily expired (unlike when lifetime is set to a non-zero value).

Comment: I didn't say I was using a cookie. I said that I was using a SESSION variable which is like a cookie, but is only on server side. A cookie would be vulnerable as it is on client side. Extending the time out is not an option, as the reason is too long to go into.

Comment: Since row selection appears to be a 100% client-side operation I see no reason to avoid client-side storage until the user is done is data is submitted for final processing. Furthermore, session abuse tends to be terrible when you browse a site using different tabs.

Comment: The client does not make the id. The id is in the table, which obviously he can see. Problem with storing an id in a cookie is this. A cookie can be tampered with, but a session variable can't. Anybody can take a cookie and change it and re-submit it. So session variables are safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a hidden id on the form is the right way to go. You just need to make sure the user is allowed to edit that form/id before saving. You should also do normal sanitisation checks on the variable.

Comment: I have used a hidden id before, but I was worried that using this method might be open to attack. I mean in this instance the id isn't secret, but I don't want them changing the id, so that they can add to something they shouldn't add to you see.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams I think we haven't understood how your current code works and assumed the ID was already somewhere in the page HTML.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams It doesn't matter if they change the ID to something else, if they are allowed to edit that something else. So when you save the form, you need to do a check to see if that person can see and or save that form. You should be doing that anyway.

Comment: They are not allowed to change the id, but when I click the button if the id is in a hidden field I still need to post that id from jquery, but anything that is posted can be tampered with. Which is why I was using a SESSION variable which can't be tampered with, but then I have the problem with the session timeouts. I don't want to extend the session, because of various reasons, but I would like to know if the SESSION can be brought back after expiring

Comment: Why can't they change the ID?

Comment: @ThomasWilliams But what happens **before** they click? Where does that ID come from? Isn't it already on the page? You said: "The id is in the table, which obviously he can see". HTML can be tampered with even easier.

Comment: Html can't be tampered with unless they have access to the server, but they can tamper with what sent in a post. They can't bypass the html because we are using https. The id is in a table. The id is not secret, and they can't change the html, but they could fake a post, if you know what I mean. My question though is still can a session be brought back after expiring though?

Comment: No it can't. You will still need to do the same server side checks to make sure that the user is allowed to see the form pre session initiation.

Comment: I have decided to read the id off the page, then in php I will check if that id is associated with that user. If not it will stop the process happening. That means if somebody does hack it and send a false id then it won't do anything. So they won't see any information they shouldn't

Comment: @ThomasWilliams In most modern browsers you can right click on an element, select *Inspect element* and alter the HTML to your liking. I mean that you don't even need to download third-party hacking tools.

Comment: Wow you are right. I knew I could change css in firebug, but didn't know you could actually change html. That would have been a big security risk. I just changed my the id and clicked submit. Luckily my new function will stop incorrect ids

Comment: This is even worse than I thought. I have tables with id filtered to different people. I have just found out I can edit an id in a table and get records I am not supposed to get access too. This is terrible. I must write a function to stop this happen. This should be put in massive big letters on stack overflow.